# How to write option x p in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I need to write a function `option x p` which tries to apply parser p. If p
fails, it returns the value x, otherwise the value returned by p.

```
 option :: a -> Parser a -> Parser a
 option :: a -> Parser a -> Parser a
 option x p = case parse p x of
         [] -> x
         [(v,out)] -> [(v,out)]
```

Above is what I wrote but it doesn't work. What's the problem here?

Comment: What is the type of `Parser` and `parse` ? There are lot of libraries in Hackage with it's own `Parser` out there.

Comment: It depends on the specific type, as Sibi said, but it could be something like `p <|> pure x`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume `type Parser = ReadS` and `parse = id` in this answer.

You are close, but you are trying to pass your parser a value of the *result* type -- when you almost certainly want to pass your parser the string that it should parse to produce a result. Additionally, you have to return not just a value of the result type, but also the unparsed bit of the input stream. So:

```
option x p s {- extra argument -} = case parse p s {- pass s, not x -} of
    [] -> [(x, s)] {- return a value, and don't consume any input -}
    other -> other {- might as well work correctly if there are multiple parses -}
```